# I dropped my laptop. SMART says there are bad sectors. Can I fix this?

Tags: 10.04, hardware, smart

I have Ubuntu and Win7 both installed on my laptop.

I was working on Windows when I dropped the laptop from about 3.5feet in air. Ever since, windows is unable to boot. But Ubuntu works just fine.

When I ran SMART, it shows me there are a few bad sectors. I'm attaching a screen shot of the report.

Can anyone suggest what must be done?

Here's the image:

[image: disk utility screenshot with current pending sector count of 3]

Comment: What do you get when booting windows?

Comment: @Prasad Just a the windows 7 loading screen followed by a black screen. Nothing loads. Even in safe mode it just freezes after loading certain files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `badblocks` command from the Linux command line. Refer to the man page for detailed information: `man badblocks`.

As an example, I run `/sbin/badblocks /dev/sda` on a monthly basis to find problems. I never had to use this tool to actually fix bad sectors, thats why I have to point you to the man page.

BTW: You cannot fix the NTFS filesystem from Linux, you need Windows for that. Yuo can however check the disk for bad blocks as described and it can do some relocation of bad sectors (which doesn't affect the filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html#sdisk

See the section on bad block reassignment. You can repair this
at the filesystem level, or the block level, seeing that you have
multiple filesystems, and one is non-native, I would recommend the
later. You can run badblocks and pipe the output to sg_reassign.

Backup any critical data before continuing.

Comment: I have no idea whatsoever about file systems or anything of the sort. Are you sure I should invest my time into learning how that tool works?

Comment: It's your data, what's it worth to you?